# Использование шаблонного кода из другого проекта

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++

Подскажите, каким образом можно добиться, чтобы шаблоны C++ можно было помещать в статические/динамические библиотеки? Сейчас мне приходится обходиться связыванием проектов для использования написанного кода "библиотеки". Что приводит к долгому компилированию. Или вариантов нет?

Comment: Да и сам вопрос лишён смысла. Какие статические/динамические библиотеки, если речь идёт об инструменте времени компиляции.

Answer (score 4):

Шаблоны, как следует из имени, представляют собой некий абстрактный код, инстанциирование и компиляция которого происходит *для текущего проекта* (очевидно, в момент его компиляции).

Таким образом, как только вы пишете `#include "header-whatever"`, в котором располагается шаблонный код, **а потом применяете** некоторый шаблон, описанный в файле `header-whatever`, то именно в этот момент и происходит компиляция кода шаблона.

Вообще говоря, время компиляции шаблонов - отдельная тема для беседы, т.к это все происходит очень долго даже в новейших версиях компилятора. Единственное, что могу отметить - по результатам бенчмарков в `gcc` ветки `4.6+` производительность компиляции темплейтов была сильно оптимизирована и он делает это пошустрее, нежели, например `cl` или `ipp`.

---

Конкретно по вопросу *(хотя и довольно бессмысленно)* - вы вполне можете сделать некоторый нешаблонный класс, который внутри себя будет использовать шаблонные методы, разбить этот класс на реализацию и объявление *(`cpp` и `header` файлы)* и скомпилировать этот файл в отдельную статическую библиотеку.

Таким образом шаблонный код будет инстанциирован, и, соответственно, вместо header-файла с его кодом нужно будет линковать библиотеку с кодом вашей обертки.

Смысла в этом действии немного, но время компиляции, предположительно, уменьшится :)